# Stochastic differential of Bessel process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $ \underline{B}_{t}=(B_1(t), \dots, B_d(t))$ be a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion.

How to calculate the stochastic differential of $ \Vert{\underline{B}_t}\Vert$?

$\Vert . \Vert$ denotes the $d$-dimensional Euclidean norm, i.e. $\Vert \underline{X} \Vert=\sqrt{x_1^2+ \dots + x_d^2}$.

$ \Vert{\underline{B}_t}\Vert$ is also called as [Bessel-process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_process).

Comment: How? Using Itö's formula as dumbly as possible (what else?).

Comment: @Did: Thank you, but AlmostSurely has already answered my question using Ito's lemma.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because each $B_t^{(i)}$ is independent of the others, the only quadratic variation terms will be $d\left[B^{(i)},B^{(i)}\right]_t$. To avoid confusion in notation, I will say $B_t$ is an $n$-dimensional BM. Applying Ito's lemma to $\Vert B_t\Vert$,

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial B_t^{(i)}}\left\Vert B_t\right\Vert &=\frac{B_t^{(i)}}{\left\Vert B_t\right\Vert} \\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \left(B_t^{(i)}\right)^2}\left\Vert B_t\right\Vert &= \frac{\Vert B_t\Vert - \frac{\left(B_t^{(i)}\right)^2}{\Vert B_t\Vert}}{\Vert B_t\Vert^2} \\
&= \frac{\Vert B_t\Vert^2 - \left(B_t^{(i)}\right)^2}{\Vert B_t\Vert^3} 
\end{align*}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
d\Vert B_t\Vert &= \frac{1}{\Vert B_t\Vert}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nB_t^{(i)}\,dB_t^{(i)}\right)+\frac{1}{2\Vert B_t\Vert^3}\left(n\Vert B_t\Vert^2\, dt- \sum_{i=1}^n \left(B_t^{(i)}\right)^2\, dt\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\Vert B_t\Vert}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nB_t^{(i)}\,dB_t^{(i)}\right)-\frac{\Vert B_t\Vert^2}{2\Vert B_t\Vert^3}\, dt + \frac{n}{2\Vert B_t \Vert}\, dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\Vert B_t\Vert}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nB_t^{(i)}\,dB_t^{(i)}\right)+\frac{n-1}{2\Vert B_t\Vert}\, dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\Vert B_t\Vert}\left(\frac{1}{2}(n-1)\, dt + \sum_{i=1}^nB_t^{(i)}\,dB_t^{(i)}\right).
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Does this formula agrees the one present [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_process)?
I mean $ \frac{1}{\Vert B_t\Vert}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nB_t^{(i)}\,dB_t^{(i)}\right) $ is the stochastic differential of a 1-dimensional Brownian motion?

Comment: Yes. To see that it's a standard BM, define that as $$X_t$$, so that $$d\left[X,X\right]_t=dt$$ and by Levy's characterization of BM, it is again a BM.

Comment: @AlmostSurely I need to find a solution of the SDE $dX_t=\frac{(n-1)/2}{X_t}dt - dB_t$. Is it true that your answer is also a solution to this one, because $-dB_t=dB_t$?

Comment: @AlmostSurely How can I see that $X_0=0$?

Comment: The Ito's formula cannot apply here, since the euclidean norm is not differentiable at 0.