# Inverse Bessel Process as continuous local martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $B$ be a $n$-dimensional brownian motion. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023110/stochastic-differential-of-bessel-process) shows, that

$$\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n\int_0^t\frac{B^i_s}{||Bs||}dB^i_s,||B_t||\Big)$$

is a weak solution of $dX=\frac{n-1}{2X}dt+dW$.

Now I would like to show, that $||B||^{-1}$ is a continuous local martingale iff $n=3$.

Let $n=3$. Using the SDE, $$||B_t||^{-1}=\int_0^t||B_s||ds+W_t$$

Therefore $||B||^{-1}$ is a continuous local martingale, since this is sum of two continous local martingales? But wouldn't this apply to any other dimension as well?

How could I deal with the other direction?

I'd appreciate some hint or help on this problem. Thanks for your attention, again!

Comment: Well, wait... I'm actually not that sure, if $dX=\frac{n-1}{2X}dt+dW$ implies $dX^{-1}=d\frac{1}{X}=\frac{3-1}{2\frac{1}{X}}dt+dW=Xdt+dW$...

Comment: Because $N=3$, $d(X^{-1}) = -X^{-2}\,dW$>

Comment: Yes, exactly. If $n\ne 3$, there will be a stochastic integral $H dt$ left, which is not a local martingale.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The function $$h:(0,\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty),\quad h(x):=x^{-1}$$ has derivatives

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(x)&=-x^{-2}\\
\quad\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial^2 x}(x)&=2x^{-3}
\end{align}$$
Using both Ito's lemma and the SDE, one finds

$$\begin{align}
||B_t||^{-1}=h(||B_t||)&=h(||B_0||)-\int_0^t||B_s||^{-2}d||B_s||+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t2||B_s||^{-3}d[||B||]_s\\
&=h(||B_0||)-\int_0^t\frac{n-3}{2}||B_s||^{-3}ds-\int_0^t ||B_s||^{-2} dW_s
\end{align}$$

The first and last term are local martingales. The middle term is a local martingale iff $n=3$.